# Как изменять line-height в зависимости от того, вмещается ли контент в блок

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Ребята ситуация такова:

```css
.mytext {
  width: 120px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px #c6c6c6 solid;
}

.mytext2 {
  margin-top:10px;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px #c6c6c6 solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="mytext">Тест</div>

<div class="mytext2">Тестовая информация</div>
```

Мне необходимо, что бы в зависимости от текста который вставляется в блок изменялся параметр line-height. Более чем 2 строки текста никогда не бывает, поэтому, если текст не поместился в одну строку нужно применить line-height:18px. Как это можно сделать с помощью css? Или тут прибегать нужно к js?

Comment: Да, без js тут никак

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что вам просто нужно уместить текст посередине блока?

Comment: У меня эти блоки выводятся циклом. Как определить по каждому из блоков с помощью js вмещается ли в него текст, и если нет то применить line-height?

Comment: Да все верно. Вместить нужно по центру блока (по вертикали)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы выровнить положение текста по вертикали, необязательно менять `line-height`. Достаточно обернуть текст внутри блоков в другой элемент, например, `p`, и этому `p` задать `display:inline-block;` (`и vertical-align:middle;` при необходимости) и задать ему `line-height` сразу с учетом того, что текста будет на 2 строки:

```css
.mytext {
  width: 120px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px #c6c6c6 solid;
}

.mytext2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.mytext>p {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mytext">
  <p>Тест</p>
</div>

<div class="mytext mytext2">
  <p>Тестовая информация</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Обязательно!:))